# What is the integral of $\frac{x^2}{(x^2 + 4)^2}$ from 0 to infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Have been doing fairly well with these integrals and then BAM! This one is really throwing me off. Residue theory is not serving me well this time around...

Wondering if anyone could give me a hand?

My original answer was $\pi$, which I know is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried a trig substitution?  e.g.  $x = 2\tan(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your integral has order greater than two you can use the formula: $$\mathrm{Res}(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( (z-c)^{n}f(z) \right).\tag{1}$$

We have: $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}.$$ First thing you should notice is that this is an even function because $f(x)=f(-x)$, so you must divide by $\frac12$; now change your variables to $z$ and find the poles.$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z^2+4)(z^2+4)}=\frac{z^2}{(z^2+4)^2} =\frac{z^2}{(z-2i)(z+2i)(z-2i)(z+2i)}$$ We found poles at $\pm 2i$ with order two, so you must apply formula $(1)$ noted above (we are taking only the upper semi circle so $-2i$ is not needed here).

We now can take the limit and use formula $(1)$. Thus we have: $$\lim_{z\to 2i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^2}{(z+2i)^2}=\frac{4iz}{(z+2i)^3}=\frac{4i(2i)}{(2i+2i)^3} \\ \frac{8i^2}{(4i)^3}=\frac{8}{64i}=\frac{1}{8i}.$$ 
Now multiply by $\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$, (why?) and the answer is $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: Please elaborate further. Thank you for the answer by the way. I've been wondering how to deal with poles of order greater than or equal to 2. I made a guesstimate with 1/(1+x^2)^2 but haven't had the same luck with the others I've tried

Comment: Savage, I have edited, take a look and feel free to ask me any further questions.

Comment: Hey sorry to take so long to respond. I figured out what I doing wrong with the formula you supplied. You've helped tremendously my friend. Thank you!

Comment: Savage, no problem!

Answer (score 3):

You could use residue theory by extending your integral to the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+4)^2}dx.$$

This follows because your integrand is even. From there, it should be a straightforward application of the residue theorem with your pole at $\pm 2i$ (depending on how you choose it).

Edit: Also you could do the indefinite integration by hand. It is amenable to trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Okay so I was doing the steps correctly. I guess I'm just doing the residue wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't it possible to keep the integral from 0 to infinity. Makes it easier right, since there is no residue?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=2\tan(a)$ and see what happens. Move your cursor over the gray area for the answer.

> We then get that$$I = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{x^2dx}{(x^2+4)^2} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{4 \tan^2(a) \cdot 2 \sec^2(a) da}{(4 \sec^2(a))^2} = \dfrac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2(a)da = \dfrac12 \cdot \dfrac{\pi}4 = \dfrac{\pi}8$$